# Static equilibrium | A beam is hanging by two ropes with angles and there is a block on it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I have this problem model and I'm trying to get the solved equations for the distance $d$ and the tension $\vec{T_2}$ with the known values of angles $\alpha$ and $\theta$, $\vec{P_1}$, $\vec{P_2}$ and $l$.

- The green $\vec{P}$ are the weights
- The pink $τ$ are torques

I'm not sure about the signs of the torques and how to replace the equations with each other to get the final equations that only need the known values

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three equations: The sum of the vertical components of the forces = 0. The sum of the horizontal components of the forces = 0. and The sum of the torques about a chosen point = 0.  I would take the torques about point (A).  Your three unknowns will be: $T_1, T_2$, and d.

Comment: From $τ_A$ I got $\vec{P_2}d-\vec{P_1}(l/2)+\vec{T_2}sin(\theta)l=0$

From $\sum{\vec{F_x}}=0$ I got $\vec{T_1}cos(\alpha)+\vec{T_2}cos(\theta)$

and from $\sum{\vec{F_y}}=0$ I got $\vec{T_1}sin(\alpha)+\vec{T_2}sin(\theta)-\vec{P_2}-\vec{P_1}=0$.

Finally, I made a linear equation system 

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
-\vec{P_2}d+0s\vec{T_1}+in(\theta)l\vec{T_2}=\vec{P_1}(l/2) \\ 
0d+sin(\alpha)\vec{T_1}+sin(\theta)\vec{T_2}=\vec{P_2}+\vec{P_1} \\ 
0d+cos(\alpha)\vec{T_2}+cos(\theta)\vec{T_2}=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Comment: In working with components, you don't need the arrows over the vector magnitudes. Also one of the cosines needs to be negative.

Comment: Yes and $\vec{T_2}$ it was wrong.
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
-\vec{P_2}d+0\vec{T_1}+sin(\theta)l\vec{T_2}=\vec{P_1}(l/2) \\  
0d+sin(\alpha)\vec{T_1}+sin(\theta)\vec{T_2}=\vec{P_2}+\vec{P_1} \\
0d-cos(\alpha)\vec{T_1}+\vec{T_2}cos(\theta)=0\\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
With $\vec{P_1}=20N$, $\vec{P_2}=68N$, $\alpha=37°$, $\theta=57°$ and $l=2,46m$ I got $d=1,77m$, $\vec{T_1}=48,08N$ and $\vec{T_2}=70,52N$ but it's weird to me that $d>l/2$ because the block is at the left of the center, and I used $\tau_A$ for torque. I mean, I thought $d$ it was going to be smaller than $l/2$

Comment: I agree with your calculations. You still do not need the arrows. They do in fact indicate wrong directions for the components.